# Как закрыть экземпляр проводника с помощью Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Каждый раз когда я сажусь за изучение Python, я открываю определенное кол-во программ и файлов которые мне понадобятся при обучении и это делать не удобно. Открыть Notepad++, затем CMD, затем проводник, в проводнике открыть QTTabBar закладку, открыть книгу, так что решил реализовать это все, через инструменты что доступны в Python, но столкнулся с проблемой (код привел ниже), скрипт грубый и примитивный но это пока что, для закрытия программ пользуюсь методом `os.system` и "Убийцей процессов" `taskkill`, проблема в том, что при закрытие обычных программ не возникает проблем, так как требуется просто ввести имя процесса который хочешь остановить, но процесс проводника `explorer.exe` существует не в одном экземпляре, и процесс `explorer.exe` что отвечает за открытые папки и процесс `explorer.exe` который отвечает за меню пуска и прочего ни чем не отличаются, и как то явно указать на то, что мне необходимо закрыть определенный процесс `explorer.exe` не получается, подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать лучше всего

```
# Файл №1 - открывает все нужные приложения
import subprocess 
import time

subprocess.Popen('explorer "D:\"') 
subprocess.Popen('D:\\Program\\ShareX\\ShareX.exe')
time.sleep(1)
subprocess.Popen(('start','D:\\Miscellanea\\Programmig\\Programming-Python\\Книги\\Укус_Питона.pdf'),shell = True)
subprocess.Popen('D:\\Program\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe')

# Файл №2 - закрывает все нужные приложения
import os 

os.system('taskkill /pid ShareX.exe')
os.system('taskkill /pid PDFXCview.exe')
os.system('taskkill /pid notepad++.exe')
```

Answer (score 0):

В современных версиях Windows explorer не создает отдельных процессов под каждое открытое окно. Чтобы заставить его сделать отдельный процесс, нужно вызвать его с параметром /separate. Однако этот параметр несовместим с заданием папки в качестве второго параметра. Таким образом, стандартный набор из taskkill и explorer не позволяет это делать.

А вот nircmd позволяет. Он закрывает окно по его заголовку, неважно, explorer это или нет:

```
nircmd win close title "Заголовок окна"
```

Например, у меня при открытии диска С: в explorer заголовок окна "SYSTEM (C:)" - с указанием метки тома. Поэтому я пишу:

```
nircmd win close title "SYSTEM (C:)"
```

И именно это окно закрывается.

Скачать nircmd можно на сайте автора: https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html

Comment: Выглядит хорошо, но возникла пара вопросов так как я нуб в этом, я так понял это не какая то библиотека для Python, а  утилита для командной строки и следовательно в коде импортировать ничего не нужно? Скачал архив с сайта, там было пару `exe ` файлов, запустил и попробовал ввести код, выскочила ошибка `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` ругалось на слово `win`, что я сделал не так? У меня Windows 7 и на каждое новое окно проводника открывается новый процесс `explorer.exe`

Comment: Да. Поскольку нет задачи сделать обязательно на python, я предложил дополнительную утилиту. Так оно намного проще. В архиве два exe-файла, вас интересует только nircmd.exe, ему ничего больше не нужно. В том каталоге, где лежит nircmd.exe, или в любом каталоге при условии, что nircmd.exe находится в PATH, вы вызываете командную строку и пишете: `nircmd win close title "Заголовок окна"`. После этого названное окно закрывается. Работает это вне зависимости от количества процессов и во всех ныне живых версиях Windows. Далее вместо окна командной строки вы можете использовать system().

Answer (score 0):

Перечитал вопрос, в вашем случае всё проще:

```
p = subprocess.Popen("explorer.exe D:")
p.kill() # Или p.terminate()
```

Способ для двух скриптов:

```
import subprocess
import time

kill_list = []
p = subprocess.Popen("galculator")
kill_list.append(p.pid)


# Сериализуешь kill_list, десериализуешь в другом скрипте
print(kill_list)
time.sleep(2)

import os
import signal

for pid in kill_list:
    os.kill(pid, signal.SIGTERM)
```

---

```
import psutil

def kill_last_proc(proc_name):
    last = None
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        if proc.name() != proc_name:
            continue

        if last is None or proc.create_time() > last.create_time():
            last = proc

    if last is not None:
        last.kill()

kill_last_proc('explorer.exe')
```

При желании можно попробовать выцепить не последний запущенный, а, скажем, проанализировать список открытых файлов)

Comment: Первый способ по какой то причине не работает, не закрывается проводник, в cmd нет сообщения что команда отработала `os.system('taskkill /pid ShareX.exe')`,`os.system('taskkill /pid PDFXCview.exe')` и `os.system('taskkill /pid notepad++.exe')` работают то есть закрывают процессы, а вот проводник не закрывается

Comment: Нет под рукой винды, уж извиняй)